# Send parameters between view controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parameters

Before Xcode 5, I use for send parameters between viewcontrollers in the .h file

```
NSString *test;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *test;
```

and in the .m use

```
@synthesize test;
```

and in the first view controller use:

```
SecondViewController *testC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
testC.test = @"Something ...!";
```

but it always show null in the debugger what is the problem or is there another way ?

Comment: This is not at all related to xcode. And I don't even start these tiring discussion about Apple's NDA.

Comment: What exactly shows null? And where? You are creating a brand new instance of `SecondViewController` and assign some value to its `test` property.

Comment: When i send the parameter as testC.test = @"Something ...!"; and in the SecondViewController use NSLog(@"%@",test); return (null) it must return Something ....! so what is the solution ?

Comment: Are you perhaps using segues? Then your whatever you alloc-init will be simply be ignored. You need to set this in `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: Most probably you are dealing with two different instances of `SecondViewController`. You can doublecheck that by nslogging self within `SecondViewController` and `testC` where you assign the string to `test`. Do they share the same address?

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Do not explicitly declare instance variables (ivars) to back up your properties. When the property is synthesized, it automatically creates ivar for you. If you create ivar manually, like above, you only introduce an opportunity to end up with typo resulting in two ivars, one of which will be `nil`. There is no benefit to explicitly declaring your instances variable anymore, and only can introduce problems.
2. I wouldn't even advise having your own `@synthesize` line anymore. The compiler does this for you and it does something equivalent to `@synthesize test = _test`. This is following best practice that your instance variable should have a leading underscore in its name, minimizing the chance of accidental use of ivar when you intended property.

In terms of what's going on, it could be many things, but it's hard to tell without seeing more complete code sample, but I suspect some problem with your manually defined instance variable.